# Laravel testing how to make sure job is pushed to the queue multiple times with Queue::assertPushed

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I am writing some tests for a website and I can't seem to figure out how to test that a job was dispatched let's say 5 times using `Queue::fake()` and `Queue::assertPushed()`.

I've tried putting multiple `Queue::assertPushed(SomeJob::class)` but that always passes the test no matter how many of those I put.

I've tried googling various things but found no useful info. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assert that a job was pushed **$n** no of times

```php
Queue::assertPushed(SomeJob::class, $n);
```

[Laravel Docs - Mocking - Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#queue-fake)

Comment: but the argument at that position in the `assertPushed` function is called `$callback`, so that can't be right?

Comment: Actually, in the docs it says it is the number of times...so that must be it. Thanks, I've missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `assertPushed()` is the amount of jobs pushed to the queue. This is also described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#queue-fake).

```
Queue::assertPushed(SomeJob::class, 5);
```